# pytorchの関数gatherの処理内容について

Tags: python, pytorch

[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch)の関数`gather`の処理内容が公式ドキュメントを読んでもよく分かりません。
例えば**Example**の`t`が、どのような計算をした結果、出力のようなテンソルになるのか、
具体的に教えていただけないでしょうか。

**Example:**

```
>>> t = torch.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
　　　　>>> torch.gather(t, 1, torch.tensor([[0,0],[1,0]]))
　　　　tensor([[ 1,  1],
　　　　        [ 4,  3]])
```

`dim = 0`だと、上記の入力tは下記のような出力になります。

```
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 2]])
```

**公式ドキュメント：**
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather

ご回答、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

公式ドキュメントを拝見いたしました。3Dのテンソルに対する計算式が載っていますね。
これを2Dのテンソルに置き換えるには、添え字のkと書かれた部分を削除すればok。

```
out[i][j] = input[index[i][j]][j]  # if dim == 0
out[i][j] = input[i][index[i][j]]  # if dim == 1
```

この定義式通りに動いているように思います。
下記は理解しやすいかどうかわからないですが、対応関係が見えるように行列を配置してみました。

```
#dim==0の時 indexは行番号を表しており、その行番号に対するinputの値をoutputとする
#列方向に対してはinputとoutputは同じ列を見ている。
 input
   1 2     
   3 4  

 index
   0 0
   1 0                 

output                      #output
   1 2     #input[0][0] input[0][1]
   3 2     #input[1][0] input[0][1] 

#dim==1の時 indexは列番号を表しており、その列番号に対するinputの値をoutputとする
#行方向に対してはinputとoutputは同じ行を見ている。
input  index  output                     #output
  1 2    0 0     1 1    #input[0][0] input[0][0]
  3 4    1 0     4 3    #input[1][1] input[1][0]
```